# Downloading images with malformed urls

Tags: java, java-8

I am attempting to download any given image url found on a given website. The problem i am running into is URLs of the form:

```
<img src="//domain.com/img/logo.png">
```

As you can see above, the image url is missing the protocol, which results in a malformed URL exception when attempting to download the content with the below snippet:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    URLConnection connection;
    try
    {
        connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.connect();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {...}

    try (final InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream())
    {
        int bytesRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {...}
```

Is there a better way to do this, while accounting for the potential missing protocol?

Comment: How exactly are you getting the URLs?

Comment: @hev1 Lets just suppose they are provided in a List<String> urls to be processed.

Comment: Those URLs are _protocol-relative_ URLs. Since `src=` is in a web page that was fetched via _some_ protocol (http or https) this means the image source should be fetched using the _same_ protocol as the page used.  What are you going to do with URLs that omit the server name, such as `src="../images/thatone.png"`?

Comment: There is no way around knowing the *base URL* of the page. If you know it, you can simply use [`new URL(baseURL, imageLocation)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL-java.net.URL-java.lang.String-) to construct your image URL. Note that you don’t need to find out whether the image location has a protocol or not, this constructor will already do the right thing in either case.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for the protocol and if it is not there, add it into the url.

```
 public String handleUrl(String url, boolean secure){
  if(url.startsWith("//"){
   if(secure){
    url = "https:"+url;
   } else {
   url = "http:"+url;
   }
  } 
  if(!secure&&!url.startsWith("http://"){
     url = "http://"+url;
  }
  if(secure&&!url.startsWith("https://"){
   url = "https://"+url;
 }
   return url;
}
```

To check if a URL is valid, use `URLValidator`:

```
UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();
urlValidator.isValid(URL);
```

Comment: How would i know if its secure or not? http vs https? Suppose the part of the code that downloads the images is isolated from the site url and has no knowledge of what the page's security protocol is. So you cant deduce it from the source site url's protocol

Comment: @JohnBaum if these are webpages parsed by you, remember that a browser would use the same protocol for getting the resources as it was using when getting the page.

Comment: @JohnBaum You could also put it into a `HashMap` with the `URL` and the protocol derived from the first 5 characters of the url of the website you got the image from.

Comment: Is there a better way to check for a missing protocol rather than startsWith?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the check-and-fix (so add the protocol from code if it is missing) approach shown in the other answer already, I would point at [`openStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream()). Assuming it is a safe method which does not leak and so on, you could get away with a single try-with-resources block, and hope that the `InputStream` correctly shuts down the connection (which you would not even touch in this case):

```
if(url.startsWith("//"))
    url="http:"+url;
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (final InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream())
{
    int bytesRead;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{...}
```

I just hardcoded http here, the emphasis is on the try-block.

Answer (score 0):

The images have no malformed URIs embedded.   They are valid in the context they have been generated.  They are relative URIs, like the following one:

```
#
```

(a single, null anchor reference)  These kind of URIs appear in documents that can be downloaded in several different contexts (and so, the missing information has to be provided by the downloader, who is providing it)  For example, if you download a document, that has a relative reference to itself, you can use something similar to:

```
../other_place/index.asp?page_index=3#footer_marker
```

is this valid as an absolute URI? not, you need to provide all the missing parts of it, based on the document you downloaded first, being e.g.

```
https://www.example.com/first_place/index.html#top
```

you should replace it into:

```
https://www.example.com/other_place/index.asp?page_index=3#footer_marker
```

but in case you got it from:

```
ftp://user:password@ftp.example.com/public/distribution/first_place/index.html#top
```

you should use instead:

```
ftp://user:password@ftp.example.com/public/distribution/other_place/index.asp#footer_marker
```

(beware that ftp doesn't know about query strings, so probably asking for an asp page would result in an error)